Ebike selection based on electric assistance configuration
I am residing in Netherlands and started using ebikes around a year ago. My average daily commute is 30 km but sometimes it goes up to 50 km and very rarely 100 km. I had been using Hitway bk8 and Amslod Hamilton bikes. What I liked about those bikes was the amount of boost I would get during ride. I like to ride a bit fast. So, I mostly ride above the set limit of 25 km/hr when motor stops assisting anymore.
With all basic info stated above, my Amslod bike display has broken twice. It's apparently not available in the market and I was able to arrange a used replacement somehow for the first time. But I couldn't be that lucky anymore. New one from Amslod directly costs a lot so I am now planning to discard that bike and get another one. First and foremost, I want to get an ebike whose parts are available. I came to the conclusion that any bike using bosch and bafang mid engines have parts easily available in my locality. But the bikes I have tested so far seem to have different style of providing assist/boost. They provide immediate boost but that boost is quite less than the one I am used to. The user needs to do significant work along with motor even at the highest assist level. That's sort of hybrid mode. So, even with like 400W battery, the claimed action radius of those bikes are 150+ km on lightest assist and around 60km on full assist. I suppose that is due to the motor doing less work as compared to my old bikes. All the bikes I have tested so far were having bosch mid engines.
It's quite difficult to explain this to shopkeepers here verbally so my question is, what is the deciding factor in setting boost configuration in a bike? I know, I can ask for 600+ watt battery if I want my bike to cover larger distances but what can I ask shopkeepers to give me if I want motor to provide more boost throughout? Like, mid, front or rear motor may be? Or some specific brand etc.?

Welcome to the site - this feels like a Shopping question and would be closed as off-topic.  Can we refocus it more on the main point, which seems to be the User's power input requirements and the different style of providing assist/boost.

Are you considering the faster 45 km/h speed pedelecs? You need a brommer certificaat or driving licence but if that is not a problem you will get a bike aimed at the speed you actually ride.

Maybe try a Yamaha one. The highest boost level is strong (and power-thirsty). On regular mode you get somewhere around 200km.

Thank you very much for your valuable comments. Indeed, I wanted to buy an ebike now so my question was not about suggestions of specific models. Rather, I wanted to get an understanding of different setups of ebikes in general. May be I couldn't formulate my question well.
